# combining multiple data frames from the global environment

Tags: r, dataframe

In my global environment I have multiple data frames from different `.csv` files. Each data frame is one day of observation of trading activity. Due to some performance challenges I had to perform some data preprocessing while I was uploading each `.csv` file in R. The result is in the following image:

[image]

Now I would I like to combine each data frame in the consecutive order: for example

```
masterDataFrame <– rbind(durData_IBM_AskSide1, durData_IBM_AskSide2)
masterDataFrame <– rbind(masterDataFrame, durData_IBM_AskSide3)
masterDataFrame <– rbind(masterDataFrame, durData_IBM_AskSide20)
```

My first approach was first to combine all the `csv` files in one and then perform my data preprocessing steps. This resulted in a very large data frame and the data preprocessing steps took over 10 minutes. The time aspect isn't my major issue, the problem was that between to consecutive days( ending of one day, starting of the following up day) my code produces an "event" which resulted in values which are wrong. So I had to treat each day separately and start anew for each trending day. The workaround was just an If statement that checked If `date[i] == date[i+1]`. By the way my data frame is sorted ascending for each trading day and I have time column which looks like this

[image]

is of type `POSIXlt`.

This resulted in an overall process which took over 20 minutes while performing my steps while uploading took just 1 one minute. Now I really like to know

a) how can I combine my resulting data frames into one master data frame with a loop approach?

b) while combining them how can I delete the already used data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one non-loop approach.

```
#Create name of dataframes
datanames <- paste0('durData_IBM_AskSide', 1:20)
#Combine them into one
combine_data <- do.call(rbind, mget(datanames))
#Remove them from global environment
rm(list = datanames)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

dir(pattern = "*.csv") %>% #change the path name to match yours after the first quotation mark
  purrr::map_dfr(read_csv)
```

Comment: My data is already in my global r environment and there exist also data frame called durData_Amazon[1:20]. So I only want to combine durData_Amazon[1:20] and durData_IBM[1:20]

Comment: Mark, You need to post a repex so that we can help you. Also, I suspect the avenue you're pursuing this is not the way. Can I suggest that need to fix the'event' you referred to so that consecutive obs can simply be appended.

Comment: I already fixed that event. I still looking for a way to combine existing data frame into one data frame. With a loop approach for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "repex"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you Dom, I will keep it in mind if I going to ask another question. All the best